# Passing string to a Javascript function does not work

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to pass a string to a javascript function which opens that string in an editable text area. If the string does not contain a new line character, it is passed successfully. But when there is a new line character it fails.
My code in PHP looks like

```
$show_txt = sprintf("showEditTextarea('%s')", $test_string);
$output[] = '<a href="#" id="link-'.$data['test'].'" onclick="'.$show_txt.';return false;">';
```

And the javascript function looks like -

```
$output[] = '<script type="text/javascript">
   var showEditTextarea = function(test_string) {
                 alert(test_string);
    }
    </script>';
```

The string that was successfully passed was "This is a test" and it failed for "This is a first test

This is a second test"

Comment: You're missing the `<` in the `</script>` tag.

Comment: Are you escaping the $test_string first? i.e. convert \n to \\n

Comment: You should not write JS with PHP. Think to redesign your code to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is nothing escaping your javascript variables... json_encode is useful here. addslashes will also have to be used in the context to escape the double quotes.

```
$show_txt = sprintf("showEditTextarea(%s)", json_encode($test_string));
$output[] = '<a href="#" id="link-'.$data['test'].'" onclick="'.htmlspecialchars($show_txt).';return false;">';
```

Comment: $show_txt = sprintf("showEditTextarea(%s,%s,%s,%s)", $sid, json_encode($dstring), $dversion, $dtr_version);
$output[] = '<a href="#" id="link-'.$data['sid'].'" onclick="'.addslashes($show_txt).';return false;">';

Comment: wrap  $sid, $dversion and  $dtr_version in json_encode calls as well. The only way this will work is if those values are integers

Comment: sprintf("showEditTextarea(%s,%s,%s,%s)", json_encode($sid), json_encode($dstring), json_encode($dversion), json_encode($dtr_version));

Comment: What do you mean by "The only way this will work is if those values are integers" in your previous comment?

Comment: <a href="#" id="link-category_name" onclick="showEditTextarea(\"category_name\",\"Deseo de volver a trabajar (WWA) correction\\r\\n\\r\\nDeseo de volver a trabajar (WWA) correction\",\"1\",\"1\");return false;">

Comment: @ManojPandey updated answer... use htmlspecialchars instead of addslashes and you should be good.

Comment: @ManojPandey the statement about the integers is because they will be seen as numbers without being enclosed in quotes, after looking at your return code only the $sid property needs to be wrapped in the json_encode call but it wont hurt for the others to be.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript does not allow newline characters in strings. You need to replace them by `\n` before the `sprintf()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try replacing all spaces in the php string with \r\n before you pass it to the JavaScript function? See if that works.

If that does not work then try this:
str_replace($test, "\n", "\n");

Replacing with two \ may work as it will encapsulate.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid storing HTML or JS in PHP variables as much as possible, but if you do need to store the HTML in a PHP variable then you will need to escape the new line characters.

try

```
$test_string = str_replace("\n", "\\\n", $test_string);
```

Be sure to use double quotes in the str_replace otherwise the \n will be interpreted as literally \n instead of a new line character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, that deletes new lines:

```
$show_txt = sprintf("showEditTextarea('%s')", str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $test_string));
```

Or replaces with: `\n`.

```
$show_txt = sprintf("showEditTextarea('%s')", str_replace(PHP_EOL, '\n', $test_string));
```